# Async workflows and user interaction: how to implement a 'back' function

Tags: c#, async-await

We are trying to use async workflows to handle user interaction. The idea is that we provide a number of basic possible interaction (upload a file, prompt for some data etc.) - implemented as Web forms - and the users of our system can write workflows running on the server combining these interactions:

```
  var uploadResult = await DoUpload();
  // . . .do stuff with uploadResult .. ..
  var formResult = await DoForm()
  // . . . do stuff with formResult
```

We have this all working, except for the handling of a 'Back' button: in the example above the call to `DoForm()` prompts for some data, and because it is the second form in the workflow it should have also a 'Back' button, that when pressed go back to the initial upload form.

The obvious way would be to return a `BackClicked` flag in the result of each interaction, but it should then be tested and handled by the workflow code - we'd prefer something that works automatically.

Here is the code of a simple console application that replicates what we are doing:

```
class Program {

  class Step {
    public string Prompt;
    public TaskCompletionSource<string> Tsc;
  }

  /// <summary>User interactions executed so far</summary>
  static List<Step> s_Steps = new List<Step>();
  static bool s_Continue = false;

  /// <summary>Example of a (very basic) user interaction</summary>
  static Task<string> ReadString(string prompt)
  {
    TaskCompletionSource<string> tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    try {
      s_Steps.Add(
        new Step() { Prompt = prompt, Tsc = tsc }
      );
      s_Continue = true;
    } catch (Exception exception) {
      tsc.SetException(exception);
    }
    return tsc.Task;
  } // ReadString

  static async Task TheWorkflow()
  {
    var str1 = await ReadString("String 1");
    Console.WriteLine("String 1='{0}'", str1);
    var str2 = await ReadString("String 2");
    Console.WriteLine("String 2='{0}'", str2);
  } // TheWorkflow

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    // Start the workflow...
    TheWorkflow();
    // ..and then execute it
    while (s_Continue && s_Steps.Count > 0) {
      s_Continue = false;
    Back:
      var step = s_Steps[s_Steps.Count - 1];
      if (s_Steps.Count > 1) {
        Console.Write(step.Prompt + " [back]: ");
      } else {
        Console.Write(step.Prompt + ": ");
      }
      string result = Console.ReadLine();
      if (s_Steps.Count > 1 && result == "back") {
        s_Steps.RemoveAt(s_Steps.Count - 1);
        goto Back;
      }
      step.Tsc.SetResult(result);
    }
  }
}
```

when typing `back` at the second prompt the code tries to re-execute the first task, but fails because it already completed.

Is there a way to make it work - i.e. call in some way the continuation of a previously executed task?

Comment: In short, no. You're looking at a pretty big redesign of your core types, and I don't think you'll be able to tie it all together with an `async` method. P.S. Beware the Inner-Platform Effect.

Comment: Thanks @StephenCleary, I suspected so, but I'd liked some confirmation before scrapping the idea.